# Using NSAutoreleasePool with NSURLConnection

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsautoreleasepool

I am trying to follow the XMLPerformance example to make an xml parser of my own.  So far I'm having the hardest time making autorelease pools work, I get a crash the instant I recreate a pool.

I narrowed down the issue to this test case:

### PoolCrashTest.h

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>

@interface PoolCrashTest : SenTestCase
{
  @private
  NSURLConnection *connection;
  NSAutoreleasePool *downloadAndParsePool;
  BOOL done;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURLConnection *connection;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSAutoreleasePool *downloadAndParsePool;

- (void)downloadAndParse:(NSURL *)url;
@end
```

### PoolCrashTest.m

```
#import "PoolCrashTest.h"

@implementation PoolCrashTest

@synthesize downloadAndParsePool, connection;

- (void)downloadAndParse:(NSURL *)url {
  done = NO;
  self.downloadAndParsePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  self.connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
                     initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
  if (connection != nil) {
    do {
      [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                               beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    } while (!done);
  }
  self.connection = nil;
  [downloadAndParsePool release];
  self.downloadAndParsePool = nil;
}

#pragma mark NSURLConnection Delegate methods

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
    didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  [downloadAndParsePool drain];
```

**crash after this line ^**

```
  self.downloadAndParsePool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
}

- (void)testPoolCrash
{
  NSURL *dumpURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:///some.xml"];

  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAndParse:) 
                               toTarget:self withObject:dumpURL];
  sleep(10);
}

@end
```

Can someone explain how to properly purge autorelease pool in a NSURLConnection delegate running in a thread?

I have tried to follow XMLPerformance as close as possible...  I'm targeting Lion with mostly default project settings.

Comment: Does it work if you skip drain/alloc pool in didReceiveData? Also i think connection will be leaked as you alloc and retain (via the proptery) and then only release once (assign property to nil). You should probably autorelese it after alloc/init.

Comment: Mattias: yes, and I should have mentioned that the crash happens in [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode] line, or, rather, it's the last line with source code available in the backtrace -- top of the trace is AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) method, which made me think that I was trying to unrelease some other pool created elsewhere.  You're right about connection leak -- that was my sloppy copying-and-pasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

craig is correct when he says you're over-releasing your pool. In a non-GC environment, `release` and `drain` have the same effect. In a GC environment, `release` is a no-op *for any object*, so `drain` must be used instead. I'd just use `drain`.

However, `NSAutoreleasePool` objects aren't really things you should be making a property of your class; they'll work best for you if you restrict their use to a lexical scope. There are a couple of ways you could use a pool in the code you posted above which would be sufficient.

Remember when you're spinning your run loop that it's going to be popping in and out of the call to run the run loop in the common modes; so you could do this instead:

```
if (connection != nil) {
  do {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode 
                             beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    [pool drain];
  } while (!done);
}
```

and you'd be draining any autoreleased objects created in the particular turn of the run loop. Because the connection's delegate callback will be called due to this invocation of the run loop, any autoreleased objects created in the delegate callback will be cleaned up when this pool drains.

If you're not comfortable with this, you could place a pool inside your delegate method depending on how much work your delegate method is likely to be doing:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // Do whatever work you want here
    [pool drain];
}
```

And in your case, it would have roughly the same effect.

I would strongly recommend doing something like my first example above and eliminating the autorelease pool behavior you have right now. Keeping `NSAutoreleasePool` objects to a single lexical scope facilitates everything from debugging to safe exception handling when it becomes necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just adopt your method.  One thing I overlooked is that I had zombies enabled, and that increased memory usage.  I thought I was leaking something.

Comment: Good point about the pool's scope - I don't use them often enough, didn't know they shouldn't be ivar'ed. Very helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

**You're over-releasing your pool.**

I'm re-reading your question to make sure I understand, but if you check out the [NSAutoreleasePool Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll see that `release` and `drain` should not **both** be used. (It's nearly identical to simply calling `release` twice.) Only use `drain`:

> In a garbage-collected environment, there is no need for autorelease pools. You may, however, write a framework that is designed to work in both a garbage-collected and reference-counted environment. In this case, you can use autorelease pools to hint to the collector that collection may be appropriate. In a garbage-collected environment, sending a drain message to a pool triggers garbage collection if necessary; release, however, is a no-op. In a reference-counted environment, drain has the same effect as release. **Typically, therefore, you should use drain instead of release.**

**Edit:** [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807035/best-way-to-periodically-drain-the-autorelease-pool-on-a-long-running-background) might help you understand how you should use a periodically-drained `NSAutoreleasePool` in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Dont think he over releasing as he alloc and assigns a new pool in didReceiveData, but the release in downloadAndParse should probably be a drain

Comment: But the alloc/init occurs once, then there's a release **and** a drain. That's over-releasing.

Comment: autorelease pool alloc/init occurs in both `downloadAndParse` **and** `didReceiveData`. The retain/(release or drain) count is in balance but as @chris points out the stack of pools for the current thread can get messed up when you don't restrict your own autorelease pool to one scope.